# Using substring on a column in R

Tags: r, substring

How would I use substring to only use the first 3 digits of the postal code in the data sheet?

```
YEAR    PERSON    POSTALCODE   STORE_ID
2012    245345    M2H 2I4       20001319
2012    234324    L6N 3R5       20001319
2012    556464    L6N 4T5       20001319
```

This is a piece of code I tried, however my data sheet appeared with 0 objects after I added the substring part of the code (I'm guessing I made an extremely dumb mistake):

```
combined <- merge(df1, df2, by.y="PERSON")
store1  <- combined[combined$STORE_ID == 20001319 && substr(combined$POSTALCODE, 1, 3), ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`substr(combined$POSTALCODE, 1, 3)` gives you

```
# [1] "M2H" "L6N" "L6N"
```

So one possible selection could be

`combined[combined$STORE_ID == 20001319 & substr(combined$POSTALCODE, 1, 3) == "M2H", ]` which gives you the subset

```
#   YEAR PERSON POSTALCODE STORE_ID
# 1 2012 245345    M2H 2I4 20001319
```

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the last 3 digits of the postal code from every postal code in that column? There are thousands of postal codes in the data sheet, however I only want to use the first 3 digits of the postal code.

Comment: @AJC That would be `combined$POSTALCODE <- substr(combined$POSTALCODE, 1, 3)`.

Comment: Yes, however when I do that I get a set of values. How would I import those values into the data sheet?